# Match and return value in new column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What is the best function to use if:

1. I want to add 2013 sales (Sheet1) to an existing sheet (Sheet2) under column 2013, and
2. If the customer does not exist in the 2013 sheet (Sheet2), to be able to insert it accordingly (from Sheet1).

Sheet1:

```
CUSTOMER    2013    
ABC         25      
BBB         10      
DDD         40      
XYZ         20      
YYY         30      
ZZZ         15
```

Sheet2:

```
CUSTOMER    2010    2011    2012    2013
AAA         1       2       3   
ABC         5       10      15  
BBB         4       5       6   
FFF         3       6       9   
XYZ         4       6       8   
ZZZ         2       4       6
```

Comment: See `VLOOKUP()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SUMIF`, e.g. if 2013 figures are in sheet called 2013 with Customers in column A and Sales in B then in summary sheet where customer is in A2 use this formula in 2013 column row 2 copied down

`=SUMIF('2013'!A:A,A2,'2013'!B:B)`

If the customer doesn't exist in 2013 sheet you get zero

The alternative is `VLOOKUP` with `IFERROR`, i.e.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'2013'!A:B,2,0),0)`

See [this example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/30etqu6jnkdcr32/SUMIF_VLOOKUP.xlsx)

Comment: I am so sorry but the formula did not work! I got all 0

Comment: hi barry if you have time can you send me the example in an excel sheet my email is moesak123@gmail.com thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, I think I misunderstood - where you have a customer "DDD" which is in sheet1 but not sheet2 you want to add that to sheet 2?

Comment: yes indeed, but also the sumif and the vlookup functions did not return any value?

Comment: In the above example, and if the formula worked as it should, in sheet2 E4 the return value should be as follows:                                  Customer 2010 2011 2012 2013 AAA 1 2 3 0 ABC 5 10 15 25 BBB 4 5 6 10 FFF 3 6 9 0 XYZ 4 6 8 20 ZZZ 2 4 6 15 DDD 0 0 0 40 YYY 0 0 0 30

Comment: OK, past my bedtime here but I'm attaching a link (see my answer) to show how the VLOOKUP/SUMIF works (see yellow cells) just to get values from existing customers, not adding any......